# Permutation and Combination- Rowing a Boat

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The crew of an 8 member rowing team is to be chosen from 12 men, of which 3 must row on one side only and 2 must row on the other side only. Find the number of ways of arranging the crew with 4 members on each side.
a)40320
b)60480
c) none of above.

My analogy - I tried creating all possible ways 8 people could be selected from 3 groups ( A- 7 people ,B -2 people ,C- 3 people )i.e
7 from A , 1 from B +
7 from A , 1 from C +
6 from A , 2 from B +
6 from A , 2 from c +
6 from A , 1 from B , 1 from C +
.
.
.

But this is getting too long.. any thoughts on a simpler method ?

Comment: Well... what have you found so far?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Can you add an explanation of what you've tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: The problem splits into two parts. Choosing 8 men from the 12 to be in the boat, with 4 on the left and 4 on the right. And then ordering these 8 chosen men in the boat. Have you had a go at either?

Comment: @amWhy I have edited the question

Comment: The question should be more clear about what exactly constitutes an arrangement. To me it seems that it amounts to assigning to each man one of three options: left, right or neither, and in such a way that each option is selected for $4$ different men. In other words there is no additional ordering among the $8$ rowers (nor on the $4$ that are left out). Another point of difficulty "must row on one side only" suggests that they _must_ be selected, but I think the interpretation should be "can only row on the left" (respectively right), so can either be selected for the left, or not selected.

Comment: @barakmanos I have edited the question

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then those $2$ and $3$ people are already "fixed", so you have to choose the remaining $3$ out of $7$ people, and then choose $2$ out of the $3$ to go on one side, and the remaining $1$ to go on the other side. Overall, the number of ways to do it is $\binom73\cdot\binom32\cdot\binom11=105$. So either I am misinterpreting something in the question, or the answer is c.

Comment: Without restrictions on people being selected, there are $\binom{12}{4,4,4}=34650$ ways to distribute $12$ people into three groups of size $4$ each. Since the true answer must be less than that, "none of the above" would be the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. First allot the "special" 3 for 1 side & "special" 2 for the other.
2. The 7 men left can be allotted in ${7\choose 1}{6\choose 2}$ = 105 ways
3. Now permute them to get ans = $105\cdot4!\cdot4!$ = 60,480 ways

Answer (score 0):

3 can sit on one side only let us assume thats side B therefore 2 hv to be 
seated on side A. We are left with 7 rowers . We can choose 2 on side A in 7C2 ways and after we have chosen 2 for side A we are left with 5 rowers and 1 seat on side B This selection can be made in 5C1 ways. Now on both sides the rowers can be permuted in 4! Ways. Since it is mentioned that the group of 3 can sit only on one side and 2 rowers on the other we cannot interchange the sides. Hence solution is 7C2×5C1×4!×4! = 60480

@@-- side A 7C2 × 4!
@@@- side B 5C1 × 4!

PS. Chosen implies combinations and arrangements imply permutations

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. The following are necessary conditions that answers to old question must fulfill:
1) Completeness and clearness 2) Give a substantial contribution to the discussion 3) Being [well-edited](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).