# A problem in permutation/combination

Tags: permutations, combinations

**Q.A boat is to be manned by eight men,of whom $2$ can only row on bow side and  $1$ can only  row on stroke side,in how many ways can the crew be arranged?**

*I approached the problem in the following way:*

-Since there were $8$ crew members.$2$ of them should be assigned to bow side.$1$ applied permutation.
 -Now,$1$ member out of $6$ should be assigned to stroke side,I again applied permutation.

No. of ways crew can be assigned to row is $8!/5!$.I think No. of ways crew can be assigned to row = No of ways can the crew be arranged

Well,this does not solve the problem.

Where is my mistake?

[[Permutation and Combination- Rowing a Boat](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147691/permutation-and-combination-rowing-a-boat) is a similar question.But it didnot attracted any answer]

Comment: i used both tags because I donot know which one should be used.

Comment: How many people can or should be assigned to each side? $4$?

Comment: No information about that in the problem.

Comment: So what, you can put $7$ men on the bow side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that 4 men are to be put on each side, first place 2 "special" on the bow side and 1 "special" on the stroke side. Now there are 5 left.

Choose 2 men from the 5 left for the bow side in ${5\choose2}$ = 10 ways. The remaining automatically get assigned to the stroke side.

So the answer is just 10, if order does not matter.

[If order does matter , it will be $10\cdot4!\cdot4!$ ]